# I accidentally overwrote a text file. Anything I can do?

Tags: files, data-recovery

I had a somewhat important file `stats.txt`, which I accidentally overwrote through a Matlab script (`dlmwrite('stats.txt',...)`). Is there anything I can do to recover this information? It comes from code that takes many hours to run, so I'd rather not have to do it all over again.

If it matters, I'm running Linux through a remote terminal (ssh-ing to my school's computer).

Comment: If you edited that file at some point, your editor may have made a backup copy - I know `joe` does this, it has saved me more than once...

Comment: Start using version control. Git is the most popular choice. Mercurial is also a worthy option.

Comment: Your school's computer staff may be making backup copies of the files on their systems. You can ask them.